# My .label class will be displayed only on emulated screen of intel-xdk

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, intel-xdk

I am using intel-xdk and bootstrap 3 to make some apps and I now I have to deal with a strange problem.I use .label class inside a .jumbtron.When I use intel-xdk emulated screen all goes well but when I test the same app on a real device everything inside .label class will not be displayed.

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center text-info bg-danger">
        <div class="label label-danger">RGBA Colors V 1.0</div>
       fittiit
       </div>
```

***UPDATE***
The problem persists even after changing the div tag with a span tag and when I compile the app I have the content of the label class missing.
Have you any ideas of what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by changing div to span:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center text-info bg-danger">
        <span class="label label-danger">RGBA Colors V 1.0</span>
       fittiit
       </div>
```